# How do I access a class variable of a mixin in a reactjs class?

Tags: reactjs

How do I access a class variable of a mixin in a reactjs class?
e.g.

```
var MixinExample = {
    stateVar : '',
    mixinFunct : function(){
    console.log("Hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `this.mixinVariablename` in react class member functions

For eg

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MixinExample],
  render: function(){
    console.log(this.stateVar);
  }
});
```